# rails angular js subdomain

Tags: angularjs, api, ruby-on-rails-4, subdomain

I am new to angular js and I want request the server which is already implemented with subdomain for api part . I am facing issues when I want request the server api part from angular js . I tried like the following

```
1st case:

@service = $resource('/api.lvh.me/properties/:property_id/rates/:id',{})

2nd case:

@service = $resource('/api.lvh.me/properties/:property_id/rates/:id.json',{})

3rd case: 

@service = $resource('http://api.lvh.me:3000/properties/:property_id/rates/:id.json',{})
```

no one is working for me , but when I tried the following its working fine

```
 @service = $resource('/properties/:property_id/rates/:id.json',{})
```

In this case its hitting the normal controllers(not the api part/controllers) and I had to manage json type requests and rendering data accordingly , but I dont recommend this as I have already built the api part with sub domain constraint in rails , I want to go with this .

my routes defined like the following

```
 namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} , :path => '' , :constraints => {:subdomain => 'api'} do
  ....  
 end
```

Can anyone please help how to request the api part on the server .

Thanks ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I fixed it by using [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem , I configured middileware as they suggested in application.rb file and changed my routing way like the following

```
$resource('http://api.lvh.me:3000/properties/:property_id/rates/:id',{})
```

Hope it helps for someone.